# Tensor components and tensor interpretation

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $R^i_{jk}$ be the tensor components of a $C^{\infty}(M)$ multi-linear map $R:\mathscr{X}^2(M)\to\mathscr{X}(M)$

> Prove that $R^i_{jk}=\overline{R}^i_{jk}$ where $\overline{R}$ is the $(1,2)$ interpretation tensor of $R$.

This is a new definition, that I crossed with, and I am trying to make sense of it.

The definition is the following:
$$\overline{R}(\theta,X_1,...,X_s)=\theta(R(X_1,...,X_s))$$

So, let's consider local coordinates and an open set $U$ containing p, then:

$R(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\sum R^k_{ij}\partial_k$

Let $dx_l\in T_pM$
$\overline{R}(dx_l,\partial_i,\partial_j)=dx_l(R(\partial_i,\partial_j))=dx_l(\sum R^k_{ij}\partial_k)=\sum dx_l(R^k_{ij}\partial_k)=R^l_{ij}$.

I think this proves the claim.

**Question**:

Is this proof correct? If not, how should this be solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof looks correct to me.